# jQuery: fix a div at the bottom edge of the window when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

I have a sidebar on my website that should stick to the bottom of the browser window once its height is reached - I know this sound complicated, but it probably isn't.

I did a little demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dJXS2/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var bh = $(window).height();
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var eh = $('#element').height();
    var eo = $('#element').offset();

    if ( st >= (eo.top + eh) - bh ) {
        //$('#element').css('position', 'fixed');
    }


});
​
```

So, again - what I want:
You see the div `page-height` that just makes the body longer for testing purposes. The green sidebar is shorter than the page height. Once the user scrolls further than the bottom of the green bar I want the green bar to be fixed at the position it's currently at. So I don't want the user to see the whitespace underneath the green bar. When scrolling up again, I ofcourse want the normal scroll behaviour back and the green bar shouldn't be fixed anymore.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use position: fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/dJXS2/5/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var bh = $(window).height();
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var el = $('#element');
    var eh = el.height();
    if ( st >= (100 + eh) - bh ) {
        //fix the positon and leave the green bar in the viewport
        el.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            left: el.offset().left,
            bottom: 0
        });
    }
    else {
        // return element to normal flow
        el.removeAttr("style");
    }

});
```

Comment: thank you! any idea why I can't use the offset value of the element? I need this because my header height could be dynamic!

Comment: Have you tried to use the offset? it should plug right in, that's why i moved away from a css class. http://jsfiddle.net/dJXS2/5/

Comment: You can't use `el.offset().top` because it will be different once you make it fixed. You would need to calculate and store that outside of the scroll event.